# opening a file with a variable name

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010, excel-2007

Hello I have current Problem, I have a variable called Dateiname in Module1, which is a Name of a Excel File.This variable takes values such as "04_01_2017.xlsm". It can vary depending on the User Input

```
    Dateiname = Ord & mNummerGanz & "_" & Name & ".xlsm"
    ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Dateiname
```

I want to be able Activate this Excel file from another Excel file.This Excel file does some operations before in Module2 before activating the Excel file with variable Name.

When i type;

```
    Windows(Dateiname).Activate
```

I get an error such as; runtime error 9. Can aynyone help me ?

Comment: If the file is already open use `Set wb = Workbooks(DateiName)` and work with the `wb` Object (`Dim wb as Workbook`). If the Workbook is not open, use `Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Dateiname)`

Comment: What is the **actual** value of `Dateiname` when this error occurs?

Comment: empty, i know thats the reason but someshow i get the variable without any value if i Transfer it from module1 to module2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Option Explicit` in all of your modules.

Your variables from Module1 are not in scope/available in Module2.  Option Explicit will alert you to this error, as `Dateiname` is most likely undefined in scope of Module2, and has an empty/nullstring value.

If the `Dateiname` is empty/nullstring, this would always raise a subscript out of range (type 9) error, because it is equivalent to `Windows("").Activate`, and since there is no such named Window/Workbook, an error will raise.

**IF `Dateiname` is a module-scoped variable**, you can do:

```
Windows(Module1.Dateiname).Activate
```

Or preferably:

```
Workbooks(Module1.Dateiname).Activate
```

And as others have mentioned, you should probably be using a `Workbook` variable.

**IF `Dateiname` is procedure scope**

You will need to explicitly pass the variable to the procedure in Module2.  E.g.,

Module1:

```
Sub foo()
Dim Dateiname as String
Dateiname = "some value"

Call Module2.bar(Dateiname)

End Sub
```

Module2:

```
Sub bar(Dateiname as String)

MsgBox Dateiname

End Sub
```